# Re-writing Div and Grad with Differential Operators

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

I have some expressions with grad and div operators and would like to re-write the expressions so that there are no grads or divs.  Basically, I have been told that $\nabla \phi$, where $\phi = 1/4 \pi |\textbf{r}|$, can be re-written as

$\nabla \phi = \frac{\textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|} \frac{\text{d}\phi}{\text{d}|\textbf{r}|}$.

I might need to refresh my knowledge of vector calculus, but I suppose this just follows from the chain rule?

Edit:

$\nabla \nabla \phi = \frac{\nabla (\textbf{r})}{|\textbf{r}|}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\phi + \hat{r} \nabla \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \phi \bigg)=\frac{\textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|} \frac{\text{d} \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|} + \frac{\textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|}\frac{\textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|} \frac{\partial}{\partial r} \bigg( \frac{\partial}{\partial} \phi \bigg) = \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|\textbf{r}|}\frac{\text{d} \phi}{\text{d}|\textbf{r}|} + \frac{\textbf{r} \otimes \textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|^2} \frac{\text{d}^2 \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|^2}     ,                 $

$\nabla \nabla \nabla \phi = \nabla \bigg(  \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|\textbf{r}|}\frac{\text{d} \phi}{\text{d}|\textbf{r}|} + \frac{\textbf{r} \otimes \textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|^2} \frac{\text{d}^2 \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|^2} \bigg)=\nabla \bigg(\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|\textbf{r}|} \bigg) \frac{\text{d}\phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|} + \frac{\delta_{ij}}{|\textbf{r}|} \nabla \bigg(\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial r} \bigg) + \nabla \bigg(\frac{\textbf{r} \otimes \textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|^2} \bigg) \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} +\frac{\textbf{r} \otimes \textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|^2} \nabla \bigg( \frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial r^2} \bigg) =      \nabla \bigg(\frac{\delta_{ij}}{|\textbf{r}|} \bigg) \frac{\text{d}\phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|} + \frac{\delta_{ij} \otimes \textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|^2} \frac{\text{d}^2 \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|^2}   +   \frac{\delta_{ij} \otimes \textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|^2} \frac{\text{d}^2 \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|^2} + \frac{\textbf{r} \otimes \delta_{ij} }{|\textbf{r}|^2} \frac{\text{d}^2 \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|^2}      + \frac{\textbf{r} \otimes \textbf{r} \otimes \textbf{r}}{|\textbf{r}|^3}  \frac{\text{d}^3 \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|^3}    ,          $

$\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi = \nabla^2 \phi = \frac{\text{d}^2 \phi}{\text{d} |\textbf{r}|^2}     $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression for the gradient will work with *any* function that is a function purely of the radius (i.e., no angular dependencies).  In spherical coordinates:

$\displaystyle  \nabla\Phi = \hat{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Phi + \hat{\theta}\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Phi+\hat{\phi}\frac{1}{\sin{\theta}}\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\Phi  $

If $\Phi$ is a function of $r$ only,

$\displaystyle  \nabla\Phi = \hat{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\Phi$

But $\hat{r}=\bf{r}/|\bf{r}|$ and $\partial/\partial r = d/d|\bf{r}|$.  Make those substitutions and you get your expression.

Comment: And for example, if I then want to $\nabla \nabla \phi$ it's just repeat the same rule?  What would $\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi$ be?

Comment: @Tom   Again, if $\Phi$ depends only on $r$, it would just be $\partial^2\Phi/\partial r^2=d^2\Phi/dr^2$

Comment: I've tried a few more as practice, I'm not sure if these are correct.  One thing that I'm not sure about in the expression is that you end up with $\nabla \delta_{ij}$, what happens when you have the grad operator act on a second rank tensor (obviously I know it will have to be a third rank tensor).